# Outreg2 and regressions with interactions c.var1##c.var2

Tags: variables, regression, stata, label

I'm running a group of regressions of the form

```
reg var1 var1_iv var2_iv c.var1_iv##c.var2_iv

outreg2 using "filename", tex(pr frag) label title("title") replace
```

But when compiling the resulting tex files (I "call" the files into a main file using `\input{}`) I get an error message because of the `#` in the interaction terms.

My solution so far has been to correct each tex file manually, but since I have a lot of regressions, this is becoming quite exhausting.

Is there a more efficient way to solve this?

like labeling interactions, an `outreg2` option, a way to ignore `#` in the main tex file?

Comment: What do you want `#` to be? Within Stata, see `help filefilter`. You can also use your favorite text editor to search/replace.

Comment: Within Stata using `##` in a regression, indicates you want to interact the variables to the left and right of `##`. Using `c.` indicates those variables are continuous. When saving the regression output this interaction is labeled `c.var1_iv##c.var2_iv` which is problematic when you run the latex code. I already tried finding a way to label interactions without success.

Comment: I'm aware of what the `#` and `c.` signify in Stata. My question was, what are you substituting them for manually in the .tex file? That is, what manual adjustment are you doing? I suggested two ways in which you can do the substitutions. Don't they work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried ´filefilter´ and it works but it requires me creating a different file than the original, I would like to replace it. using search/replace is what I meant by "correcting it manually", since I have 40 tex files which I'm calling into a main, it is not very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. First option**

One way out is to use `filefilter` along with `copy`. The first command creates a new file with desired content. With the second you can "copy" that new file to its original name. Then `erase` the leftover file. An example would go something like:

```
filefilter testfile.tex testfile2.tex, ///
        from("original") to("modified") replace

copy testfile2.tex testfile.tex, replace
erase testfile2.tex
```

**2. Second option**

Another (untested) option is to use temporary files. In this case, I imagine you could originally save the .tex file to the `tempfile` and then feed it to `filefilter`. That is, the input to `filefilter` is the tempfile and the output, whatever name you want to use. See `help tempfile`.

### Edit

**3. Third option**

The previous Stata `tempfile` approach doesn't seem to work (although the first option does). But it seems simpler to use a "temporary file name" of your own (not Stata's) as a bridge towards your final file name. For example:

```
sysuse auto,clear

tempfile file

regress mpg foreign weight headroom
outreg2 using xfile, tex replace

filefilter xfile.tex filedef.tex, ///
    from("VARIABLES") to("ACHANGE") replace

erase xfile.tex
```

`xfile.tex` is the name I've used for the transition file. `filedef.tex` is the final file. Use the `replace` options accordingly, depending on your use.

Comment: I used option 3 combined with a loop over all of my files and it worked. Thanks! Still I wonder if there is a way to label interactions in Stata...

Comment: `estout`, a user-written command from SSC that is also used to output regression results, has an `interaction()` option for labeling the interaction terms. See `ssc describe estout`. If installed, just type `help estout`.